# creating new raid 5 volume

Tags: raid, windows-home-server, disk-controller

I recently purchased and installed a HighPoint HIRR2640X4SG RAID Controller card. I installed three 2 TB hard drives, and created the array:

[image: Image 1]

I booted and went into Disk Management in WHS 2011. I was prompted to initialize a new disk, which I did using a MBR. Disk Management now shows:

[image: Image 2]

I'm only able to create a new volume on the `2048.00` GB space. I'm expecting to be able to create a volume across the entire space. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this resource](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6473f30f-af22-4ce1-bc2d-e58cc35d351b/unable-to-partion-on-unallocated-space), volumes greater than 2 TB need to be created using GPT, rather than MBR.

[image]